# Credentials to JBoss AS Administration Console?

Tags: jboss

A simple newbie JBoss question.

I've got JBoss 5.1.0 GA installed (from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss/JBoss-5.1.0.GA/)) and running, and I'm trying to access the administration console:

[image]

**What are the default credentials (if any) and where do you configure these?** I didn't find an answer in the JBoss [Installation And Getting Started Guide](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html_single/index.html).

The server is running Ubuntu 9.10 but I believe that is irrelevant, as JBoss is installed outside package management.

Comment: Neither does the "Administration And Configuration Guide" seem to help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is admin/admin.

You can find and modify this in:

server/default/deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/WEB-INF/classes/web-console-users.properties

Information can be found online (on page 3):

[JBoss Admin Console Quick Start Guide](http://community.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/13711-102-1-104307/Admin-Console-QuickStart.pdf)